# AppArmor mod_php + MySQL

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, app-armor

Is there any way to get AppArmor to work with Apache2 + mod_php + MySQL?

I've already tried `sudo aa-complain apache2` and `sudo aa-logprof`, but still I get a database connection error.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, according to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1373070), the temporary fix is to add `attach_disconnected` to the `flags` at the top of the profile. Something like:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 flags=(attach_disconnected)
```